# Cannot use import statement outside a module using jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm using jest to run some tests on a lib and I've been getting the error "Cannot use import statement outside a module" after I upgraded a lib that now exports to es6, before the upgrade the tests worked just fine.

A screenshot of the error:
[image]

The jest.config.js file that I'm using:

```
module.exports = {
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src/'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.ts?$',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
};
```

The tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "types": ["jest"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": false,
    "pretty": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "baseUrl": "./"
  }
}
```

And lastly, the babel.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          ie: '11',
        },
      },
    ],
    '@babel/typescript',
  ],
  plugins: [
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
  ],
  env: {
    development: {},
    production: {
      plugins: ['transform-dev-warning'],
      ignore: ['**/test/'],
    },
    test: {
      sourceMaps: 'both',
    },
  },
};
```

I've tried pretty much every solution that I could find online but nothing seems to work. If anybody could help me that would be great, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

This is very common issue by using (`import`) an `esm` js style that causes the issue. In this case the package is `sip.js`.

#### Solution

The solution is also very common as well which we just simply configure `jest` to transform that package by using magic option `transformIgnorePatterns`. Plus, also tell `tsc` to compile that `esm` package too.

In short, here are the thing you would do:

`jest.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  transform: {
    '^.+\\(t|j)sx?$': 'ts-jest', // transpile both `ts` + `js` files
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [`/node_modules/(?!(sip\.js))`] // Keep `sip.js` to get transpiled as well
};
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^.+\(t|j)sx?$/: Unmatched ')'`

Comment: @FreePhoenix888 Check that the expression includes the \\ before the opening brace `(`. Otherwise, its treating the opening brace as an actual character, not a sub-pattern.